# Logic Apps Email Trigger - Get original Alias

Tags: outlook, alias, azure-logic-apps

Found a very similar question here: [Email aliases not returned as "To" address in logic app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60144240/email-aliases-not-returned-as-to-address-in-logic-app)

TLDR: From within a logic app "When a new email arrives" trigger, How do I get the original alias that the email was sent to?

I have a logic app that creates a ticket based off an email sent to an outlook box. Now I want to be able to choose aspects of the ticket based off of whether or not the email was sent to the mailbox itself or an alias of the mailbox. The problem I'm having is that by the time logic apps gets a hold of the email, the alias address has already been replaced with the actual box's address ("alias1@place.com" -> "actualbox@place.com").

The actual mail in the inbox has the original email's alias information in the headers, but I can only get them by looking at the properties in outlook. I've tried to get the original "To" internetheader information both within logic apps (by exporting the email to blob storage and looking at headers there) and with the Microsoft Graph API. Sadly, the email exported by logic apps doesn't have the alias information and Graph API has pretty much every header but "To". [At least one other person has lamented the lack of To](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/internetmessageheader?view=graph-rest-1.0)

That said, the actual email still has the original alias information. Can someone help me get that information in logic apps without jumping through too many hoops? A many hoop solution is welcome if none other can be found though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We arrived at a many hoop solution.

The "Primary" email box now has some rules that look at the internet headers mentioned above (**Message -> Properties -> look for 'To:'**).

If it finds an alias there, it will put the email in a corresponding folder for each alias.

Then we have logic apps listening to each of the `alias` folders which will then send the email's information to the `_Core` logic app that does the actual processing.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Export email (V2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003460#export-email-(v2)) action from the Office 365 Outlook connector. This will give you the full message with original headers (including the actual To address)!

The flow here is, trigger on the incoming email, as you already are, then add the export email action providing the message id from that trigger to pull this specific email.

From there, you you'll have one big "body" property which you'll need to interrogate to find the To address.

Caveat on this though, it doesn't work when emails are sent between mailboxes in the same Office 365 tenant. Exchange Online will "helpfully" go, "I know that address... this is the address you wanted!"

Comment: I've tried different approaches and this works the best!

Answer (score 0):

What API are you using? In Outlook Object Model / MAPI / EWS, you need to retrieve the `PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS` MAPI property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F`)